# Tooltip Bootstrap duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a navbar with icons only which I want to show only tips when the icons are touched or tapped so I did this code:

```js
$('a[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    animated: 'fade',
 placement: 'bottom',
});
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a  id="Textcolor" data-toggle="tab" rel="tooltip" data-original-title='Home' href="#sectionA"><i id="homeicon" class="fa fa-lg fa-home"></i></a></li>
        <li><a id="Textcolor2"  data-toggle="tab" rel="tooltip" data-original-title='Profile' href="#sectionB"><i id="profileicon" class="fa fa-lg fa-user"></i></a></li>
         <li><a id="Messages"  data-toggle="tab" rel="tooltip" data-original-title='Messages' href="#"><i id="messageicon" class="fa fa-lg fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
         <li><a id="Notifications"  data-toggle="tab" rel="tooltip" data-original-title='Notifications' href="#sectionA"><i id="bellicon" class="fa fa-lg fa-bell"></i></a></li>
         <li><a id="Gameification"  data-toggle="tab" rel="tooltip" data-original-title='Gameification' href="#"><i id="gameicon" class="fa fa-lg fa-gamepad"></i></a></li>
```

So actually the tip for each icon appears perfectly and just fine beneath the icon. The problem is that I want this tip from the `rel="tooltip"` to appear only for like 2 or 3 seconds. How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**jQuery**

```
$('a[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip({
   animated: 'fade',
   placement: 'bottom',
   trigger: 'hover',
   delay: { "show": 200, "hide": 1000 }
});
```

It is not the best solution, but I hope it helps you.